# Trailing tokens in Acro Package

Tags: acro

I recently installed texlive through MacPorts and I am trying to use the acro package, which I have used before, for some acronyms. I have all the acronyms defined correctly, and they print correctly, except when they are at the end of a sentence. A minimum working example is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{RR}{
  short = RR ,
  long  = rain rate
}
\begin{document}
In this sentence \ac{RR} is used before the end of the sentence.
It is very inteseting what happens when we wait until the end of the sentence to discuss \ac{RR}.
\end{document}
```

Here is the output from pdflatex:

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/MacPorts 2016_4) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
     restricted \write18 enabled.
    entering extended mode
    (./Testing.tex
    LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
    Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 47 language(s) loaded.
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
    Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
    (/atmomounts/home/grad/kwodzicki/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/cgnieder-acro-83c
    237f56dd4/acro.sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code
    .tex)
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.
    def))
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3so
    rt/l3sort.sty)
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/x
    parse.sty)
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e
    /l3keys2e.sty)
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplat
    e/xtemplate.sty)
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.s
    ty)
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspa
    ge.sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.
    sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.
    sty)
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarer
    r.sty)
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkey
    s.sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds
    .sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex
    .sty)))
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefine
    keys.sty)
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcm
    ds.sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.st
    y))
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.st
    y))
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi
    .sty))
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/translations/transl
    ations.sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/cnltx/cnltx-base.st
    y
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pgfopts/pgfopts.sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.cod
    e.tex
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfilt
    ered.code.tex))))
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.
    cfg)
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.d
    ef))
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspac
    es.sty))
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfil
    e.sty
    Package scrlfile, 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                                        Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

    )))
    No file Testing.aux.

    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pd
    f.mkii
    [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
    )
    (/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/translations/transl
    ations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl)
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    <argument> \prop_get:Nn 
                                                    \l__acro_trailing_actions_prop {.}
    l.12 ...he end of the sentence to discuss \ac{RR}.

    ? s
    OK, entering \scrollmode...
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    <argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                                                         A property list was misused.
    l.12 ...he end of the sentence to discuss \ac{RR}.

    ! Undefined control sequence.
    <argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                                                         A property list was misused.
    l.12 ...he end of the sentence to discuss \ac{RR}.

    ! Undefined control sequence.
    <argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                                                         A property list was misused.
    l.12 ...he end of the sentence to discuss \ac{RR}.

    [1{/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/var/db/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
    }] (./Testing.aux

    LaTeX Warning: Acronyms may have changed. Please rerun LaTeX.

    ) )
    (see the transcript file for additional information)</Volumes/localdata/opt/loc
    al/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
    Output written on Testing.pdf (1 page, 15517 bytes).
    Transcript written on Testing.log.
```

And here is the text that displays in the output file.

```
In this sentence rain rate (RR) is used before the end of the sentence. It is very inteseting what happens when we wait until the end of the sentence to discuss .RR.
```

As you can see, there is a non-fatal error when an acronym is used before a period (.) at the end of a sentence. The error being:

```
    ! Undefined control sequence.
            <argument> \prop_get:Nn 
                    \l__acro_trailing_actions_prop {.}
            l.12 ...he end of the sentence to discuss \ac{RR}.
```

From the output text, this results in placing a period before the acronym. Any ideas on what is going on here? I have tried to deactive-trailing-tokes, but that also gives an error. For example, if I add the following line of code after the acro package is loaded in my minimal working example:

```
\acsetup{deactivate-trailing-tokens = {dot}}
```

I get the following error:

```
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    \acro_deactivate_trailing_token:n ...emove_all:NV 
                        \l__acro_trailing_tokens_t...
    l.4 \acsetup{deactivate-trailing-tokens = {dot}}
```

I assume this is a bug introduced in a recent update as I have used this package before without issue.

Comment: You didn't update the `expl3` packages. Or updated them and missed an update to `acro`.

Comment: You've got a 'local' version of `acro` (`/atmomounts/home/grad/kwodzicki/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc/cgnieder-acro-83c
    237f56dd4/acro.sty`) which as @egreg says is out-of-sync with `expl3` (`/Volumes/localdata/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty` and so on).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue? I didn't notice this issue, but it seems that all the packages being used are from the MacPorts install except acro, which is installed but LaTeX is not using it.

Comment: @kwodzicki Don't install TeX Live with MacPorts. Use MacTeX, your TeX experience will be easier. By the way, `acro` is in TeX Live, so I'm quite surprised you need a local copy.

Comment: On my laptop I use MacTeX, however, on my machine at my work I do not have root access so I can't update packages very easily, thus why I was using MacPorts. But it seems like it isn't going to work as well as I thought it would. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a version mismatch